# How to record a remote webRTC MediaStream?

Tags: html, audio, webrtc, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to record the remote user's media stream.  The Media Stream object that is passed from the remote user appears to be very similar to the local Media Stream object generated from getUserMedia, however upon passing this into a Media Stream visualiser nothing is output (if I pass the local Media Stream the visualiser has an output).  I can hear the remote user's Media Stream so I know that something is being passed.

The remote media stream looks something like

```
active: true
id: "Q7aYJkeOt5xhHJ53c3JVhr41scl6QQEib5lt"
onactive: null
onaddtrack: null
onended: ()
oninactive: null
onremovetrack: null
__proto__: MediaStream
```

and has an audio track

```
enabled: true
id: "021f5032-a524-42ae-ad40-bf0798df89cd"
kind: "audio"
label: "021f5032-a524-42ae-ad40-bf0798df89cd"
muted: false
onended: null
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
remote: true
__proto__: MediaStreamTrack
```

The local Media Stream looks something like

```
active: true
id: "fP3smf9D78yl9YXV8jZwGPkMNL2UkwrXc2sl"
onactive: null
onaddtrack: null
onended: ()
oninactive: null
onremovetrack: null
__proto__: MediaStream
```

with an audio track

```
enabled: true
id: "32da421e-0a35-4fe4-b553-8a3206d244ec"
kind: "audio"
label: "Default"
muted: false
onended: null
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
remote: false
__proto__: MediaStreamTrack
```

The only real difference that I can see is the remote flag in the audio track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is supported since Chrome 48:

```
peer.onaddstream = function(event) {
    var stream = event.stream;

    window.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        type: 'video/webm'
    });

    recorder.start(99999999999999999);
};

btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
    if (!window.recorder) return;
    recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
        var blob = event.data;
        console.log(blob.size, blob);
    };
    recorder.stop();
};
```

Cross-browser implementation: https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

Comment: I'm intending to use a cloud based recording infrastructure such as Twilio to record the Media Streams, mainly to reduce the client side network load.  I dont see the difference between the local Media Stream and the remote other than the local can be visualised and recorded whereas the remote cannot.  Do I need to parse the Media Stream object or can I use the MediaStreamTrack and submit that to the recording infrastructure?

Comment: @muaz-khan [Chrome 49 is the 1st to support the MediaRecorder API without the flag](https://github.com/addpipe/Media-Recorder-API-Demo) .